# How to know which shard is overloaded in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

> One day we will find that one shard in our shared index is doing a lot more work than the other shards

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/one-big-user.html

How can we know which particular shard is overload?

```
/_cat/thread_pool?
/_stats?
/_status?
/_segments?
explain?
```

Answer (score 0):

In that particular example, I guess the author means that the shard got a lot bigger than the other shards (since a more popular forum would naturally have more content). You can see shard size under `_cat/shards`.

Or you can look at your Analytics data and deduce that a certain shard gets more searches than other shards. As far as I know, there is no way to directly measure the load of a particular Elasticsearch shard.